# Theme install failed

Tags: themes, installation, css

Unpacking the package…

Installing the theme…

The package could not be installed. The theme is missing the style.css stylesheet.

Theme install failed.

Answer (score -1):

Theme install failed

You go to theme folder and you `zip` only the theme file.

**Note:**

You download the theme you have `__macosx` theme folder also there.

You zip only the theme file then you upload it

[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GUHMXvXHWrc)